# Is there a formula to remove words from a cell that are listed in a column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, formula

As the title says, Is there a formula to remove words from a cell that are listed in a column?

Below is an example of what I want to achieve. Orange is what I type, green is the list and blue the result

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Microsoft365:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",,LET(X,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),FILTER(X,NOT(MMULT(--EXACT(X,TRANSPOSE(B1:B3)),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B1:B3),,,0))))))
```